# Unable to enable encryption on RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, encryption

I am trying to launch a MySQL Database Engine in RDS with ***encryption*** enabled. I am unable to enable encryption as the options **YES and NO** are ***not*** getting ***highlighted***.
May I know the reason for this ? Here is the snap of my AWS console.

[image]

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=736239

Comment: It's supported for MySQL. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateInstance.html

Comment: The database engine you selected has nothing to do with it. From the link in my previous comment: "Most likely you have selected an instance type that does not support encryption. Please see Availability of Amazon RDS Encrypted Instances at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html for more information." If you go to that documentation there is a table that shows the AWS instance types that support encryption. You have to pick an instance size that is listed in that table for encryption to be supported.

Comment: Thanxx a lot Mark. It helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason behind my problem was I have selected db.t2.micro for which encryption is not enabled. 
Availability of RDS Encrypted Instances is given in the below link :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html

Answer (score 1):

Equally, when using the new RDS user interface, encryption cannot be turned off on page 2 of the Instance Creation wizard, if db.t2.micro is selected on page 1 of the wizard.

So the solution is to choose t2.small, turn encryption off, then go back to step 1 and switch to t2.micro